# Client Server data sharing issue

Tags: android, database, client, sharing

I have a webservice with a mobile application. The user, with the application shares the data on the server - have a constraint in the DB that the name of the shared object is unique per user. Also application stores locally all created data (by the user - that is also shared).

I have the following scenario:

1. User creates data with data-name X.
2. User shares this data.
3. Server has in it DB data-name X for this user
4. User has a new phone and install the application.
5. NO INTERNET CONNECTION
6. user creates again data with data-name X.
7. it is stored only locally - since NO INTERNET CONNECTION.
8. Internet connection restored.
9. Now a BG service run and start sharing all u shared data - in the BG.
10. The problem found because of the constraint.

What should be done to solve the problem? I can popup a new window saying that it already shared and ask the user to rename/overwrite it, give option to D/L this data to its local DB etc. But since it is done in the BG - is it user-friendly to show this popup?

Any other ideas?

Probably there is a common way of doing it.

I can really use some help reagrding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

for this, you generally don't use a name or something of that sort, but UUIDs - i.e. 32-to-64 character long random strings that uniquely identify an object. When you create an object, just create a UUID on the device and sync this to the server. Heres the documentation of the [UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html) class in android.

While it theoretically feasible to have the same UUIDs, it's something you generally don't worry too much about it, as stated here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

For iOS, you can use the [CFUUID](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html) class to generate UUID

Another name for UUIDs ist GUID, Globaly unique identifiers. Hence, you remove any kind of uniqueness constraint.

Comment: Hmmm... So you recommend using UUIDs that are unique per user? But can it be that will generate an already existing UUID (exists on the server)?

Comment: UUIDs are ALWAYS unique. You just get a new one for every object. They will be unique in your whole system.

Comment: But if I have created a UUID (which is locally unique), then if installing the application on a new device with same userId, then I guess it is possible that the new installed application can generate an existing UUID (since its DB is clear etc.)

Comment: OK, so is there same functionality for iPhone?

Comment: So actually in this way of using UUIDs it means that actaully there will be no unique name constraint - am I right>

Answer (score 0):

Here is how a recent app I've done handles this:

1. A user creates a new record on the mobile device.  The new record gets assigned a negative primary key _id number.
2. The app checks for internet connection and, if a connection exists, the app does an HTTP post to the server, creating the record on the server side.  The server then sends back a response creating the new PK _id which gets updated in the app.
3. If no internet connection, the app creates a record in my db_changes table containing the table name and the PK _id of the new record.
4. A service runs in 5 minute increments which gets updates from the server and posts new data to the server.  The db_changes table is polled each time for any existing inserts or updates that yet to be posted to the server.
5. Once successful, the record from the db_changes table gets deleted.

In my situation, this works perfectly.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the problem when the changes that are to be posted has a problem with the existing server DB (such as unique constraint etc)

Comment: In my case it did, as the unique constraint was the PK _id, which needs to be generated by the server.

Comment: But I have a problem - because I defined the unique to be the NAME entry the user creates